# Get attribute from a specific element of a class

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Basically I have to develop a Tic-Tac-Toe game, here is the HTML file which I can't rewrite only reformat a bit, but the idea should stay the same.

```
{% block content %}
    <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-light">
        <button id="retry-button" class="btn btn-success">Try again?</button>
        <a href="/" class="btn btn-outline-dark">Reset settings</a>
    </nav>
    <div id="game-board" class="mb-3" data-row-num="{{ row_num }}" data-col-num="{{ col_num }}" data-win-size="{{ win_size }}">
        {% for row in range(row_num) %}
            <div>
                {% for col in range(col_num) %}
                    <div class="game-cell"
                         data-coordinate-x="{{ col }}"
                         data-coordinate-y="{{ row }}"></div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

As you can see i have a game-cell class which contains by default 9 elements. I would like to return the data-coordinate-x and data-coordinate-y when I click one of the game-cells. I had a previous try but if I clicked it returned all of the blocks not just the one i clicked on. I have to write it in Js. If you can point me in the right direction that's more than enough for me. 
Thanks!

Comment: have you tried giving it an onclick attribute to the game cell ? Something like onclick="returnCoord(this)" and getting your coord from the "this" in js ?

Comment: Yeah I know it is possible that way, the thing is we are learning DOM manipulation and I tought it's better to implement it in pure javascript. And after getting the attributes it would be nice to know the exact element because i have to change it a few times, but only the clicked one

Comment: What you posted is not HTML. Please post the rendered HTML in a [mcve] with the JS you have written so far

Comment: I think I will go with Antonie553's idea, but thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you need to access data attributes of your game-cell element. In order to do this, you need to select the element by some ID or class. I have modified your code a little to make it run inside stackoverflow`s platform. I have added an ID which i called "unique" and I also set some values into your coordinate-x and y data attributes. Please review the code bellow and see how I managed to get those data attributes. It's important to notice that this is not the only way to access them.

```js
var gamecell = document.getElementById('unique');
 
console.log(gamecell.dataset.coordinateX);
console.log(gamecell.dataset.coordinateY);
```

```html
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-light">
        <button id="retry-button" class="btn btn-success">Try again?</button>
        <a href="/" class="btn btn-outline-dark">Reset settings</a>
    </nav>
    <div id="game-board" class="mb-3" data-row-num="{{ row_num }}" data-col-num="{{ col_num }}" data-win-size="{{ win_size }}">
            <div>
                    <div class="game-cell" id="unique"
                         data-coordinate-x="172"
                         data-coordinate-y="273"></div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Its also possible to get these values using the [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) method.

```
var elem = document.getElementById('unique');

var coordX = elem.getAttribute('data-coordinateX');
var coordY   = elem.getAttribute('data-coordinateY');
```

Please, take a look at this page, it explains some aspects of data attributes:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Answer (score 0):

Simply access your clicked game-cell by: (it will find the clicked coordinateX and coordinateY)

```
document.querySelectorAll('.game-cell').forEach((game) => {
   game.addEventListener('click',function(event){
   console.log(game.dataset.coordinateX);
   console.log(game.dataset.coordinateY);
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you must to get your element by class name or id(add an id)
  than you can get its attributes like this

```
let gameCell = document.getElementById('game-cell-id');// id for example
gameCell.getAttribute('data-coordinate-x')
```

Comment: It is CLASS game-cell and that is a collection